# content on particular memory address is different than was expected in gdb

Tags: c, memory, binary, gdb, memory-address

I have variable i of type int which value is 129. I have played with various representations of this variable in gdb.

```
# Decimal format of i
(gdb) p/d i
$18 = 129


# Binary format of i
(gdb) p/t i
$19 = 10000001


# Address of variable i
(gdb) p &i
$20 = (int *) 0xbffff320


# Binary format displayed at one byte
(gdb) x /tb &i
0xbffff320:     10000001


# Decimal format displayed at four bytes (one word)
(gdb) x /dw &i
0xbffff320:     129


# Decimal format displayed at one byte
(gdb) x /db &i
0xbffff320:     -127
```

The above output is probably because of `10000001` in twos complement is equivalent of `-127` according to this [page](http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/)  if I am wrong please correct me.

According to this:

```
# Size of int in bytes:
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$22 = 4
```

I know that int consumes 4 bytes in computer memory. So if my understanding is correct then number resides on some address in memory and consumes 4 bytes (or 32 bits, or 1 word or 1/2 giant words). Then the representation of this number look like this:

```
AAAAAAAA: XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
```

where

```
AAAAAAAA is the location in memory and
XXXXXXXX is the bits of that number (i have divided this bits into four octets for better understanding)
```

So when I access int number I need to know it's address and how many bits it consumes. So int consumes 32 bits and address can be obtained using `&` operator. Here is my actual int representation in memory (BTW why does two differs is it related to endian setting on system or what?):

```
# Binary format displayed as one word (4 bytes) (I have put space between group of 8 bits for better understanding)
(gdb) x /tw &i
0xbffff320:     00000000 00000000 00000000 10000001

# Binary format displayed as four bytes
(gdb) x/4tb &i
0xbffff320:     10000001        00000000        00000000        00000000
```

Now a little bit of basic math:

```
0xbffff320:     00000000 00000000 00000000 10000001
AAAAAAAA:       XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
AAAAAAAA:       8bits    8bits    8bits    8bits

8*3=24
(24)DEC == (0x18)HEX
0xbffff320 + 0x18 = 0xBFFFF338
```

0xBFFFF338 Should be the address of my last octet. So why this gives me `11001100` instead of `10000001`?

```
(gdb) x/tb 0xBFFFF338
0xbffff338:     11001100
```

I am printing one byte. If I were printing the whole int which consumes 4 bytes (I dont't thing this is even possible in my case since I do not have variable name which corresponds to this memory but you get the point) it may be some strange numbers because I am accessing memory after the declared variables and there might be some garbage and also my 10000001 would reside in most significant octet, but why now?

EDIT:
According to suggestions I've added 3 bytes and not 24 bytes as it was before but the result is still wrong:

```
(3)DEC == (3)HEX
0xbffff320 + 0x3 = 0xbffff323

(gdb) x/tb 0xbffff323
0xbffff323:     00000000
```

Still does not return `10000001` what is wrong here?

Comment: Addresses are by byte, not by bit; why are you trying to add 24 bytes to your starting address?

Comment: I've used also with 3 bytes but gives wrong result, please see edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've solved this yourself:

```
(gdb) x /tb &i
0xbffff320:     10000001  #### Look at the address of this byte ####

# Binary format displayed as four bytes
(gdb) x/4tb &i
0xbffff320:     10000001        00000000        00000000        00000000
#                +0              +1             +2               +3
```

The integer is being stored with the least-significant byte first.  And the other 3 bytes hold 00000000

So presumably

```
(gdb) x/tb 0xbffff320
0xbffff320:     10000001

(gdb) x/tb 0xbffff321
0xbffff321:     00000000

(gdb) x/tb 0xbffff322
0xbffff322:     00000000

(gdb) x/tb 0xbffff323
0xbffff323:     00000000
```

Comment: Ah, now I see. The thing that confuses me was: `x/4tb &i vs x/1tw &i` I would like to know why both outputs differs and also why setting endian broke gdb. Thank you

Comment: If you're examining the bytes, you'll get them in order of address regardless of endianness.  If you're examining an integer, you'll get it in human-readable form (i.e. big-endian left-to-right).  I don't know what you mean when you say "setting endian broke gdb".

Comment: I apologize I confuse my SO questions. It was mentioned in my another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286616/how-is-gdb-x-command-related-to-real-memory the point is that when I set endian to big with `set endian big` I am no longer able to access variable address `&i`

Answer (score 1):

to keep it simple.  the expression added 24 bytes to the address, not 24 bits to the address.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I've also tried it with 3 bytes.