# Why is x/1tw missleading compared to x/4tb in gdb OR is x/1tw useful for something?

Tags: c, gdb

Regarding to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286178/content-on-particular-memory-address-is-different-than-was-expected-in-gdb/) post about displaying memory in gdb I was told that the int data type is being stored with the least-significant byte first. Example would be the variable `i` which stores value of 129.

```
# Display size of int
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$2 = 4

# Display 4 bytes on which int is stored
(gdb) x/4tb &i
0xbffff320:     10000001        00000000        00000000        00000000

# Display 1 word (4 bytes) on which int is stored (spaces were added for better understanding)
(gdb) x/1tw &i
0xbffff320:     00000000        00000000        00000000        10000001
```

As you can see both outputs differs. Now I know that `x/4tb` displays int as it is really stored in memory and `x/1tw` reverse it's octets. It can be verified e.g. what happen when you want to print bytes after `0xbffff320`

```
(gdb) x/1tb 0xbffff320+1
0xbffff321:     00000000
(gdb) x/1tb 0xbffff320+2
0xbffff322:     00000000
(gdb) x/1tb 0xbffff320+3
0xbffff323:     00000000
```

My question is: why is `x/1tw` misleading compared to `x/4tb` in gdb or if is `x/1tw` useful for something?

Comment: How is it misleading? Different flags ask gdb to interpret the data differently. If you asked it to show you the ascii values at that address it would should you something different, but that wouldn't be misleading, it would just show you what you asked for. If you asked it to show you the floating point value stored at that address it would show something different again. Why is that misleading?

Comment: The command `x/4tb` displays a binary representation of each byte of a four-byte sequence starting at the target address.  The command `x/1tw` displays a binary representation of one (four-byte) machine word at the target address.  *These are different things*.  The latter is a particular interpretation of the former, if you want to think about it that way.

Comment: @Art Misleading it is because the `i` has address `0xbffff320`. The first byte stores `10000001`. When you access last byte (add 3 to `0xbffff320`) you'll get `00000000` which is OK. But when you look at  `x/1tw` output and try to access `0xbffff323` then you wont get  `10000001` but  `00000000` So in `x/4tb` output seems that bytes are in the same order as they are in memory but in `x/1tw` they are reversed. On the other hand, misleading is also `x/4tb` because it stores least significant byte first (I hope it should be last). I am trying to figure out how to best read those outputs.

Comment: It's not misleading. You're asking it to "interpret this 4 byte value at this address as a 32 bit word and then display it as bits". Is it misleading when gdb prints a byte value of 101 as 'A', when you ask it to interpret it as an ascii character even though the three lines (or the bitmap that make that picture, depending on how you prefer to see it) that make up the 'A' aren't actually in memory?